# Is possible use 2 diferent fonts in one Label of Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

How to use 2 different fonts in the same Label?

For txt1 one font and txt2 another different font

IE: Label(container_frame3, text=txt1+txt2,width=14)

Comment: I don't think so. Could you maybe use a Text widget instead?

Comment: Why don't you use two labels with different fonts instead?

Comment: No, that's not possible. If you want to mix fonts, you should use a Text widget instead of a Label. You can set the background to your widget background and omit the border, so it will look exactly like a label. You may even make it immutable by setting the state to DISABLED. So, it will look and feel like a label but you can mix any number of fonts by using tags.

Answer (score 1):

You actually built two labels, not one. So, you need to put them next to it other by adding 1 to the column on second label.

Even if you don't change variable name, each time you call Label() constructor, a new one is created. You can verify it by printing it, it will be like "frame1.Label1" and "frame1.Label2"

I changed the column in second label and took '\n's out from first one to make them stay aligned. Now it is really up to changing the background colors to make them appear as only one label.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font


root = Tk()
root.title('Example 2 fonts')
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(300, 300))

#Fonts 
big_font = Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight='bold')
small_font = Font(family='Helvetica', size=8)


container_frame3= Frame(root, highlightbackground="gray80", highlightcolor="gray80", highlightthickness=1,bd=0,bg='red')
container_frame3.grid(row=0,sticky="nsew")

datalabel= Label(container_frame3, text="{}".format('21.15 %'),width=8,font=big_font,justify=CENTER,bg='blue')
datalabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
datalabel= Label(container_frame3, text='Mbps', font=small_font)
datalabel.grid(row=0, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem  using this :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070675/tkinter-have-2-different-font-sizes-on-the-same-text)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font


root = Tk()
root.title('Example 2 fonts')
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(300, 300))

#Fonts 
big_font = Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight='bold')
small_font = Font(family='Helvetica', size=8)


container_frame3= Frame(root, highlightbackground="gray80", highlightcolor="gray80", highlightthickness=1,bd=0,bg='red')
container_frame3.grid(row=0,sticky="nsew")

datalabel= Label(container_frame3, text="{}".format('21.15 %\n\n'),width=12,font=big_font,justify=CENTER,bg='blue')
datalabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
datalabel= Label(container_frame3, text='Mbps', font=small_font)
datalabel.grid(row=0, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

that results in :[solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46CnI.jpg)

Now I have he problem to put that info in the middle of the frame I used `sticky='w'`
But doesnt work